# All-late addition hop APA

Tags: hop-utilization, late-addition, hops

Has anyone tried this or anything like it from HBC?

http://www.homebrewchef.com/AmarilloPale.html

The claim is that since the AA's are so high, adding late will balance the beer and impart an amazing nose.  I have about 6oz of amarillos in my freezer and I (and my wife) are anxious to make some space (and sessionable APA)...I don't know how this guy characterizes this recipe as an English Pale with such an abundance of american hops.

This seems to be against the grain of 60/30/5 hop additions, so I guess I simply wanted to get an answer as to why this works (or IF this works).

Comment: Three answers and no upvotes for a pretty good question.. I upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After entering this into hopville..the ibu's top in the 60's.   So in theory this should work.
Most of my other ipa's i've used 60, 10, 5, and flameout.  This would definitely ease the brew schedule.

Hopville link http://hopville.com/recipe/1174343/american-ipa-recipes/10min-amarillo-ipa

***using a 4 g boil, ibus are 69 / After upping to 6 g ibus increased to 80+****

I've already got a rye ipa on deck for Saturday, but next week I may do a 2.5 gallon BIAB of the above link and check back with this thread.

Comment: he actually goes for a 7.23 gallon boil since it is 90 minutes.  Hville is blocked @ my work, but will check it when i get home to see what that does to the IBUs (recipe estimates 66).  Mmmmm, rye-pa.  Just cracked my last double-rye from a year ago and it is one of the best i've ever made.  

Also wondering if that massive, time-consuming, borderline-ridiculous step mash is necessary.  Who does a 2 1/2 hour mash!!!??

Comment: Yep i realize that...i just used generic values to see the level of ibu's created from 10 min only additions.   2.5 hour mash does seem crazy long. My last biab was mashed for 90 minutes due to me getting caught up with a plumbing leak. that batch is ready for bottling this week....guessing it will be dry as heck!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works, more commonly know as a hopburst, I believe. Google for "baby faced assassin homebrew" and read the many blogs about a UK homebrewer turned pro who did one with Citra hops.

Comment: You beat me to it!  I was intending to edit my post to mention this is the hopburst method.  +10 good sir!

Answer (score 0):

It certainly does work but I'm not entirely convinced that there's any great advantage to trying to get IBUs late, rather than getting them early and doing a similar sized addition at flameout. In some senses it seems like a waste of hops to boil off anything you'd get from a late addition so I would lean toward a flameout addition.